# Proving the equation of an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $(c, 0)$ and $(-c, 0)$ are the foci of an ellipse, and the sum of the distance of any point on the ellipse with the foci is $2a$ I am asked to prove thath the equation of the ellipse is:
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
where $b^2=a^2-c^2$.

I tried to first write the definition of the ellipse in mathematical terms:
$$
\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=2a
$$
But when I tried to proceed from here I didn't know where should I go.

Comment: Square the last formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly faster way

**Hint:**

Move $\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$ to other side of equality to give $\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=2a-\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}$

Square both sides.

The calculation should simplify a lot as a lot of terms cancel after first step  ,compared to simply squaring original equation.

Then move terms within roots to another side and square again.

The problem should be solved.

Comment: Why this downvote ? The method is indeed attractive.

Comment: I get to $a^2x^2+a^2c^2+a^2y^2=a^4+x^2c^2$. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Navid Simplify it to $x^{2}(a^2-c^2)+y^{2}(a^2)=a^2(a^2-c^2)$ by rearranging terms. Then divide both sides by $a^2(a^2-c^2)$   . Do you get it?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal Yes. Done! Thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have deleted the downvote and I have given to the user a positive score.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- square the two members to get a form like $p+2\sqrt{pq}+q=4a^2$;
- isolate the square root in a member and square again to get a polynomial equation;
- simplify and rearrange.

---

**Addendum:**

The squaring of $4a^2-p-q$ generates the quartic terms $p^2+2pq+q^2$. After subtraction of $4pq$ from the other member, this makes $(p-q)^2$, allowing the polynomial to remain quadratic.

Comment: Very synthetic but very efficient.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I spoiled my answer with an addendum that nearly doubles the length :-(

Comment: It is true :) ahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Starting of your definition in the question if $F_1(-c,0)$ and $F_2(c,0)$ are the foci ($c>0$) and $P\in\mathcal E$ with $P(x,y)$ and $O=(0,0)$ you have

$$\mathcal E: \quad |PF_1|+|PF_2|=2a$$

Hence:

$$(x+c)^2+y^2+(x-c)^2+y^2+2\sqrt{[(x+c)^2+y^2][(x-c)^2+y^2]}=4a^2$$

$$2x^2+2c^2+2y^2+2\sqrt{[(x+c)^2+y^2][(x-c)^2+y^2]} = 4a^2$$

$$x^2+c^2+y^2+\sqrt{[(x+c)^2+y^2][(x-c)^2+y^2]} = 2a^2$$

Isolate the root and square it again....

$$\sqrt{[(x+c)^2+y^2][(x-c)^2+y^2]} = 2a^2-x^2-y^2-c^2$$

$$(x^2+c^2+2xc+y^2) (x^2+c^2-2xc+y^2) = 4a^4+x^4+y^4+c^4-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2+2x^2y^2+2x^2c^2+2y^2c^2$$

$$x^4+c^4+y^4+2x^2c^2+2x^2y^2+2c^2y^2-4x^2c^2 =4a^4+x^4+y^4+c^4-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2+2x^2y^2+2x^2c^2+2y^2c^2$$

From which, simplifying,

$$4a^4-4a^2x^2-4a^2y^2-4a^2c^2+4x^2c^2 = 0$$

$$a^4-a^2x^2-a^2y^2-a^2c^2+x^2c^2 = 0$$

$$x^2(c^2-a^2)-a^2y^2 = a^2c^2 -a^4$$

Finally, remembering that $a^2-c^2 \gt 0$ we can put $b^2=a^2-c^2$ and have like this

$$-b^2x^2-a^2y^2=-b^2a^2$$ hence the proof

$$\begin{equation} \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1  \end{equation}$$

Comment: Mh, it seems that a crazy downvoter is around.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Surely someone who doesn't know the math ahahah has voted negative.